# Jest tests broken after implementing detox

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I'd like to be able to run my detox tests and my Jest unit tests separately. For example, run detox tests with `detox build && detox test`, and my Jest unit tests with `npm test`.

After implementing detox (using mocha as the test runner), running `npm test` results in immediate error, and looks like its trying to run my detox tests (not what I'd expect)! Here's the first error I get.

`FAIL  e2e/auth.spec.js`

Not sure why its trying to run detox tests, when my package.json is pointing the test script to Jest.
`"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
}`

How do I run my jest tests now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `jest` runs all files in your project directory, that have the `.test.` or `.spec.` extension to them. That's why it picks up your detox test files and fails to execute them.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string

You have to override this default behavior in order for the two not to clash. Here's what we use in our `package.json` just for reference, you might want to change it:

```
"jest": {
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.test.js?(x)",
    "<rootDir>/src/**/*.test.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont keep you files in on folder like **tests** just add this to package.json

```
"jest": {
   "testMatch": ["**/*+(.test.js)"] 
}
```